# Passing an argument to the function , which has to be passed as an argument to another function in python

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments

I am not sure whether it is a hard question or not . I am having a function , lets say

```
def load(es , fn_set_your_data ,  input_file, **kwargs):
    success, some_ = bulk(es, fn_set_your_data(input_file, **kwargs))


def fn_index_data( index_name , doc_type , input_file , fn_set_your_data , mapping = False , force = False):

    es = Elasticsearch()
    if es.indices.exists(index= index_name):

        return "Index Already exists"

    else:

        if mapping:
            es.indices.create(index=index_name, body=mapping, ignore=400)

            print "Mapping is done"

            load(es  , fn_set_your_data , input_file , index_name = index_name , doc_type_name = doc_type)
```

Now there is another function which accepts this function as an argument , lets say global_fn . I need to pass local_fn as an argument to global_fn , with the param split_value changing every time in a loop . Eg:

```
def set_your_data(input_file, index_name , doc_type_name , split_value = 1):

    global global_count
    for skill_ , items_ in input_file.iteritems():

        main_item = items_['main_item'].strip()
        main_item_split = main_item.split() 
        if len(main_item_split) == split_value :

            query = {'item' : main_item}

            yield {
                "_index": index_name,
                "_type": doc_type_name,
                "_id": global_count,
                "_source": query
            }
        else:
            continue


if __name__ == "__main__":

    index_name_list = ['percolate_bigram' , 'percolate_ngram' , 'percolate_bigram']
    doc_type   = 'alert'


    for idx, index_name in enumerate(index_name_list):
        split_value = idx
        fn_index_data(index_name  = index_name , doc_type = doc_type , input_file = input_data , fn_set_your_data = set_your_data , mapping = mapping)
```

##### How i pass split_value to set_your_data ( local_fn ) and then pass this to fn_index_data ( global_fn ) . Hope this code is giving a good and reasonable context .

Is it doable , with `**kwargs` or something ? 
Whatever comments will be useful.

Comment: That entirely depends on `global_fn`. What does it look like? Does it accept any other arguments, which it could pass on?

Comment: Does your `global_fn` accept arguments? If yes, than you need to return value from `local_fn`

Comment: A look at `functools.partial` may be worthwhile but your description is too vague to know for sure.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Yes it accepts arguments . But , the mmain purpose of asking this is , this custom modification of local_fn ( passing arguments in loop ) is very rare case . So , I din't wanted to modify global_fn.  But anyway , how could this be done then . Should I pass split_value as an optional argument to global_fn .

Comment: If `global_fn` is allowed to accept more arguments, then you can do something like `global_fn(local_fn, split_value)`.

Comment: I will modify the qn with real case

Comment: @MichaelButscher - I hope the edited version makes it little bit more clearer

Comment: add fn_index_data() as callback function to set_your_data() function which will contain the kwargs you want to pass to fn_index_data()

Comment: So it has to be complicated right . I mean your comment is valuable , I am thinking of less complex way .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def set_your_data(split_value=1):
    def set_your_data_inner(input_file, index_name , doc_type_name):
        global global_count
        for skill_ , items_ in input_file.iteritems():

            main_item = items_['main_item'].strip()
            main_item_split = main_item.split() 
            if len(main_item_split) == split_value :

                query = {'item' : main_item}

                yield {
                    "_index": index_name,
                    "_type": doc_type_name,
                    "_id": global_count,
                    "_source": query
                }
            else:
                continue
    return set_your_data_inner

if __name__ == "__main__":

    index_name_list = ['percolate_bigram' , 'percolate_ngram' , 'percolate_bigram']
    doc_type   = 'alert'


    for idx, index_name in enumerate(index_name_list):
        fn_index_data(index_name  = index_name , doc_type = doc_type , input_file = input_data , fn_set_your_data = set_your_data(idx) , mapping = mapping)
```